# WordPress: Having trouble in pagination for plugin settings page

Tags: wordpress, plugins, pagination

Developing a plugin in WordPress and getting well but stuck on pagination for the plugin page. Here is my code downloaded from internet ( got reference from here )

```
$items = $wpdb->get_var($wpdb->prepare("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM $wpdb->review_media GROUP BY post_id")); // number of total rows in the database
```

// tested and got results as commented
    print_r($items); // say this is outputs value 2
    echo $rm_options['list_per_page']; // this is my option set with value 1

```
if($items > 0) {
        $p = new pagination;
        $p->items($items);
        $p->limit(empty($rm_options['list_per_page']) ? 20 : $rm_options['list_per_page']); // Limit entries per page
        $p->target("admin.php?page=moderate.php"); 
        $p->currentPage($_GET[$p->paging]); // Gets and validates the current page
        $p->calculate(); // Calculates what to show
        $p->parameterName('paging');
        $p->adjacents(1); //No. of page away from the current page

        if(!isset($_GET['paging'])) {
            $p->page = 1;
        } else {
            $p->page = $_GET['paging'];
        }

        //Query for limit paging
        $limit = "LIMIT " . ($p->page - 1) * $p->limit  . ", " . $p->limit;

} else {
    echo "No Record Found";
}
```

When I don't group my query by post_id it is working fine but as soon as I grouped its behaving weird. It is creating a pagination links and getting blank page. I think the reason is grouping the row. But don't know how to solve this.

Here is my table screenshot

[image]

Thanks a lot for your help...

Comment: I don't know the Class and it isn't in your question but I think there is an error here: `$p->currentPage( $_GET[ $p->paging ] )`. I guess it should be `$p->currentPage( $_GET['paging'] )`

Comment: No its not working. Class you can find here http://mis-algoritmos.com/2007/05/27/digg-style-pagination-class

Answer (score 0):

If you use WordPress `WP_List_Table` class, it will take care of the pagination and provide a default table experience for the user.

This [tutorial](http://wpengineer.com/2426/wp_list_table-a-step-by-step-guide/) covers it all, the pagination part is:

```
function prepare_items() {
  [...]
  $per_page = 5;
  $current_page = $this->get_pagenum();
  $total_items = count($this->example_data);

  // only necessary because we have sample data
  $this->found_data = array_slice($this->example_data,(($current_page-1)*$per_page),$per_page);

  $this->set_pagination_args( array(
    'total_items' => $total_items, //WE have to calculate the total number of items
    'per_page'    => $per_page     //WE have to determine how many items to show on a page
  ) );
  $this->items = $this->found_data;
}
```

And [here's the full plugin](https://gist.github.com/brasofilo/461bfe95216a2afde1d9) shown in the tutorial. And in this [other plugin](https://github.com/franz-josef-kaiser/Internal-Link-Check) you can see `WP_List_Table` in action using database data.